# Get Express app's response header in Angular 7 client

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors, mean-stack

I've been trying to access the http response header from a NodeJS app in the Angular 7 client code, but I'm unable to retrieve it. I've tried every solution I found on Stack Overflow. I still keep getting an empty header back in the browser. But it works fine on Postman.

I'm attaching the browser console log below:

```
headers: HttpHeaders
  lazyInit: ƒ ()
  lazyUpdate: null
  normalizedNames: Map(0)
    size: 0
    __proto__: Map
    [[Entries]]: Array(0)
      length: 0
```

Server-side code:

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const route = require('./routes/route');
const { mongoose } = require('./db/mongoose');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors({
    'allowedHeaders': ['sessionId', 'Content-Type', 'x-auth', 'Authorization'],
    'exposedHeaders': ['sessionId', 'x-auth', 'Authorization'],
    'origin': '*',
    'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    'preflightContinue': false
}));

// app.options('*', cors());

app.use(route);

app.listen(3000);
```

controller.js

```
exports.signupUser = (req, res, next) => {

    let user = new UserModel({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    user.save().then((user) => {
        return user.generateAuthToken();
    }).then((token) => {
        res.header({
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Authorization',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            'x-auth': token
        }).send(user);
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });

};
```

angular 7 code:

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    token: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    signup(email: string, password: string) {

        this.http
            .post('http://localhost:3000/signup', { email, password }, {observe: 'response'})
            .subscribe((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you attempting to access your header on the client side? 
The response.headers from your example is an instance of [HttpHeaders](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders). The headers arent visible as properties on the headers object itself but you can access them like this:

```
this.http
   .post('http://localhost:3000/signup', { email, password }, {observe: 'response'})
   .subscribe((response) => {
       let contentTypeHeader = response.headers.get("content-type");
       console.log(contentTypeHeader);
});
```